# Syntax : handleChange() function in React for different state attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax

Here is a handleChange function which receives the name of the state element that is going to get tied to it.

Can somebody explain to me why it has to be written like this:

```
  handleInputChange(property) {
    return e => {
      this.setState({
        [property]: e.target.value
      });
    };
  }
```

and cannot be written like this:

```
  handleInputChange(property, e) {
      this.setState({
        [property]: e.target.value
      }); 
  }
```

I don't seem to understand how to conceptualise what the first one *actually* does.

Comment: The first one returns a function, so it will most likely be used like this: `<input onChange={this.handleInputChange('someProperty')} value={someProperty} />`. The second one is also perfectly fine, but has to be used differently: `<input onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange('someProperty', e)} value={someProperty} />`

Comment: Which of them will work really depends on how you are calling the function, so you should include that in your question. E.g.`this.handleInputChange('foo')` and `this.handleInputChange.bind(this, 'foo')` would yield the same result.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, I think I misunderstood something fundamental here. So how would I call the first one, (and more importantly for me) how would I call the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one returns a function, so the result of calling it will be used as the `onChange` handler:

`<input onChange={this.handleInputChange('someProperty')} value={someProperty} />`

The second one is a regular class method that takes a property string and an event, which you can pass from the `onChange` handler:

```
<input onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange('someProperty', e)} value={someProperty} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is setting the inputs' `name` as the state key. it should be easy to handle changes. the code sample on codesandbox:  [handleReactInputsChange](https://codesandbox.io/s/94n5ox1m2o)